# Input output streams

Tags: java

If possible I would like to know what class provides input and output streams? Is it Object or System class? I am asking this because every class inherits Object class. This is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Google it! Best way to know basic thing...

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting, but did you check InputStream, OutputStream interfaces?

Comment: I know it's System class. However I also know that System inherits Object class. This is a confusing to me.

Comment: What do you mean by "provide"?

Answer (score 1):

Input and Output operations are performed by [the reader class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) and it's sub-classes. Object is a base class which provides some "usefull" methods such as equals() and toString().

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what exactly is your confusion , but i think its java.io.OutputStream and java.io.InputStream both are interfaces , based on what Stream you use , there definition in Stream class changes. i suggest you read some basic books and gets your fundamental of OOP strong.

and make full use of 
[Reference doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)